# Error when converting jupyter notebook files to .exe files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert a jupyter notebook file to an executable form. I converted it to .py file using `nbconvert --to script` file.ipynb and then to .exe using pyinstaller file.py. The problem has to do with the `%matplotlib inline`. I searched for it and i found a solution, to comment out the `%matplotlib inline` and add to my script `from IPython import get_ipython`. This works for me. I have created a tkinter window (root=tk.Tk()) and i plot some data after i press a button. The plotted figure appears in a different win=tk.Tk() window (not the same with the first one - a pop-up). When i convert it to .exe it runs normally and i see the first tkinter window. However when i press the button to plot and create the pop up figure, the cmd closes immidiately!!!

The code is:

```
#%matplotlib inline
from IPython import get_ipython
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
x=[1,2,3];y=[5,2,5]
root=tk.Tk()
def gg():
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y)
    win=tk.Toplevel()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=win)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
bt=tk.Button(win,text="press",command=gg);bt.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

[image: When i prtess the button, the cmd closes immediately and it doesn't show any figure!! I used -c option to see an error but it doesn't show me anything...]

Comment: first run .exe in console/terminal to see error messages.

Comment: to check for errors u can use a flag with pysintaller like `pyinstaller -c filename.py`

Comment: Also, dont use a `Tk()` to create a new window, because it creates new instance or new parent window, its good to just call `win = Toplevel()` and i think u missed the `win.mainloop()` there for your `win` window

Comment: i added a picture that shows the tkinter window with the button. When i press it to show me the figure, the cmd closes immediately without showing me any figure. I tried the -c option in the pyinstaller command but no error appears...

Comment: i tried to run it (the .exe file) in Anaconda and it works perfectly. It opens the figure when i press the button. However when i run it in the command line, it closes immediatlely after i press the button and it doesn't show any figure!!